# WS02 ESB GREG: remote instance and mount configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

this is my registry on ESB 4.9.0 pointing to my GREG 5.2.0 instance

```
<dbConfig name="remote_registry">
      <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB_GREG</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<remoteInstance url="https://y.y.y.46:9445/registry">
    <id>gregid</id>
    <dbConfig>remote_registry</dbConfig>
    <cacheId>regadmin@jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.45:3306/governancedb</cacheId>
        <readOnly>true</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/governace" overwrite="true">
     <instanceId>gregid</instanceId>
     <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
```

No error, but is simple ignored, the registry is local
If I change the mount point like that

```
<mount path="/_system/gov_reg" overwrite="true">
     <instanceId>gregid</instanceId>
     <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath> </mount>
```

everything works as expected.
It's an expected behaviour and I'm missing something here ?

TIA

Comment: Let me know if below answer didn't help you.

Comment: Hi @thusharaK thanks your answer
Unfortunately the first mount doesn't work for me  
It only works when I specify a mounth poath DIFFERENT than _system/governace

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Please share the error msg.

Comment: @thusharaK I mean the the _system/governace is local, not the one in greg
No error at all in the logs

TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-27 13:41:19,229]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Writing logs  {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent}

Comment: TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-27 13:41:38,481]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-27 13:41:54,096]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.eventing.internal.RegistryEventingServiceComponent} -  Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry {org.wso2.carbon.registry.eventing.internal.RegistryEventingServiceComponent}

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks fine.

Since we already mount the all governance registry from config.

```
<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>gregid</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
```

Configuring sub collection in governance registry again is not make sense. According to my understanding, However I don't see a real use case of mounting `/_system/governace` governance registry in ESB node. We can set the specific gov path for each ESB node (prod, dev, test) as,

```
<mount path="/_system/governance/env1" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>gregid</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/governance/prod</targetPath>
</mount>
```

For more validation please go through below posts,

- [G-Reg and ESB integration scenarios for Governance](https://cnapagoda.blogspot.com/2016/05/g-reg-and-esb-integration-scenarios-for.html)
- [Mounting a
  Remote Repository (WSO2 GREG) to WSO2 ESB](https://dzone.com/articles/mounting-remote-repository)

Additional reading

[Sharing Registry Space across Multiple Product Instances](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances/)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there's no duplicate mount config sections for /_system/governance in your registry.xml.

Comment: I dont have any duplicate :(

Comment: Then, try deleting the h2 databases in repository/databases/ folder and start the server with "./wso2server.sh -Dsetup" command.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I do ignore the reason, but ive cheked the system/local reg

```
/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/mount/-_system-governance
```

and noticed that in Properties  target was pointing to the old value 'instanceid'

manually corrected and now all is working fine

Below the corrispondent bit in my ansible template

```
<remoteInstance url="https://{{ greg_ip }}:{{ greg_carbon_port }}/registry">
    <id>gregid</id>
    <dbConfig>remote_registry</dbConfig>
    <cacheId>regadmin@jdbc:mysql://{{ mysql_db }}:3306/governancedb</cacheId>
    {% if  'WKR' in group_names %}
    <readOnly>true</readOnly>
    {% else %}
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    {% endif %}
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
     <instanceId>gregid</instanceId>
     <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
```